# php 7.2 upgrade error "Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with an aged wordpress theme which I really like and I only have some basic coding skills. My provider forcably upgraded my server php version to 7.2 and of course some of my scripts are breaking down.

```
public function localize( $handle, $object_name, $l10n ) {
    if ( $handle === 'jquery' )
        $handle = 'jquery-core';

    if ( is_array($l10n) && isset($l10n['l10n_print_after']) ) { // back compat, preserve the code in 'l10n_print_after' if present
        $after = $l10n['l10n_print_after'];
        unset($l10n['l10n_print_after']);
    }

    foreach ( (array) $l10n as $key => $value ) {
        if ( !is_scalar($value) )
            continue;

        $l10n[$key] = html_entity_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }``
```

According to the log the error is in the last line because in that like apparently it "Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset"

Maybe this is a lot more complicated than changing one simple thing....any solutions for that?

Comment: what is `$l10n` is it an array?  `public function localize( $handle, $object_name, array $l10n )`  It looks like it could be mixed data type `is_array($l10n)` and `(array) $l10n`  if you try to set a key on a string, you get an error like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most logical thing to do here is to change it to update in the in_array condition:

```
if ( is_array($l10n){
    if(isset($l10n['l10n_print_after']) ) { // back compat, preserve the code in 'l10n_print_after' if present
        $after = $l10n['l10n_print_after'];
         unset($l10n['l10n_print_after']);
    }
    foreach ($l10n as $key => $value ) {
        if ( !is_scalar($value) )
            continue;

        $l10n[$key] = html_entity_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```

Even if you cast `(array)$l10n` to an array, this doesn't set the variable itself to be an array ( like `$l10n = (array)$l10n`).

That said, working with mixed types can be really cumbersome.  It's better to send it only arrays or deal with the array bit first, that way you have a consistent type. Like this:

```
public function localize( $handle, $object_name, $l10n ) {
    //normalize arguments
    if(!is_array($l10n)) $l10n = [$l10n];

    if ( $handle === 'jquery' )
        $handle = 'jquery-core';

    if ( isset($l10n['l10n_print_after']) ) { // back compat, preserve the code in 'l10n_print_after' if present
        $after = $l10n['l10n_print_after'];
        unset($l10n['l10n_print_after']);
    }

    foreach ($l10n as $key => $value ) {
        if ( !is_scalar($value) )
            continue;

        $l10n[$key] = html_entity_decode( (string) $value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ArtisticPhoenix. This got rid of the Error

Comment: Hi everyone.
Any suggestions as to how to change the last line in this code so it won't throw a "deprecated function" alert in the log?

    function make_plural_form_function($nplurals, $expression) {
  $expression = str_replace('n', '$n', $expression);
  $func_body = "
   \$index = (int)($expression);
   return (\$index < $nplurals)? \$index : $nplurals - 1;";
  return create_function('$n', $func_body);

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you have another different problem I suggest posting it as a proper question.  It will be much easier to deal with that way, instead of muddying the waters.

Comment: @EaZy: if Phoenix's answer helped you fix the issue, it'd be nice if in return you accepted his answer: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: OK thank you I did accept it. even though my upvotes don't count until I reach 15

Answer (score -1):

Another possible route to fixing this is to force your server to run an older version of php if they can do that. For example with pantheon.io you can force the server to run a certain version of php in the server config file.

Unless you would like to modernize all your scripts, then ignore this.

Comment: Everything under PHP7.1 is outdated, this is a terrible advice.